# suse enterprise server libssl deleted

Tags: openssl, libssl

We made a big mistake to delete libssl while installing new version of open ssl. It is the remote suse enterprise server. It seems that ssh and wget etc. can not work fine without libssl. There is only one connect can still connect to this server by ssh since he has not disconnect from this server. But others can not connect to this server again.

Now there is only source code of open ssl. It seems the libssl could be installed if changing configure parameters of the source code of open ssl. But we do not know how to do this.

Comment: If file is still open by process, you can access it in `/proc/<PID>/fd/` directory (PID is id of process, e.g. sshd). As for compiling from source - you haven't asked a question; I'm sure it have something like README file.

Comment: thanks very much! we solved it by configuring the source code of open ssl: ./config shared zlib-dynamic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.